# how to off Rotation in Nokia device N82?

Tags: mobile, java-me, nokia, midlet

I want to lock Rotation functionality of Nokia N82 Device for my application.
Is there any attribute available for doing so?
How can i achieve this?

I have tried out `Nokia-MIDlet-App-Orientation : portrait` attribute. but cant get success.

Comment: Anyone have any idea, how to resolve this issue???